# How To Detect Email Size Issues In .NET

Tags: c#, .net, email

We have an application which sends out automatic email notifications to our users.

Those emails come from a no reply address for instance 'no-reply@blah.com'.

The problem comes when the attachments added to the automatic emails go above the limit of the receiver email server, e.g. 8 MB, or 10 MB.

Is there a way in .NET to detect that this is going to happen? If a reply comes to no-reply saying that there is a failure because the limit was exceeded that is not ideal because that address is never checked.

Is there a way of detecting whether this will be a problem before sending the email?

I guess the main problem is that the email size limit can be configured, so we don't know what it is going to be for a particular organisation.

Comment: You want to query the server before sending the email to it about it's limits? I don't think that's possible. Part of the problem you may run into, is some mail servers will respond OK even when they don't plan to deliver. My work exchange server for instance will just swallow up any email over 10MB, but return an OK.

Comment: FYI, you asked about "C# .NET". Am I correct in assuming that you know the answer is not specific to the programming language used, and that you simply want the examples in C#, since that's the language you're using?

Comment: Well yes, if there is an answer I would guess it relates to SMTP, so if it is explained with regard to SMTP, or C# then that is fine. I am using C# so I will have to implement it in C# if anything comes out of it.

Comment: Blake, that is along the lines of what I was thinking. Perhaps there is another solution though, I don't really know. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: You are routinely sending 10mb emails from a do-not-reply address? that sounds less than good email etiquete..

Comment: IanNorton - good point. I personally didn't decide that it was a good idea. Perhaps we need to take a step back and reconsider it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a thought, why don't you insert *links* to the attachments/files instead? I've been though this several times, and yes if the file to attach is personal, attach it, otherwise just put the attachment on a webserver and link to it.

That would certainly speed up mail delivery, and reduce bouncing messages.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, that's a good answer. We have considered that but there are security problems with that idea. But perhaps we should investigate this more ...

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because if we investigate this possibility more and solve the security issues with it then I think this could work out. Alternatively the system will sometimes loose emails and my product manager will have to accept the clients calling him up and complaining :)

Comment: Great to hear! As a security measure I, in one system, created a simple ticket system; where a 'ticket' was generated by the system - e.g. create a string with memberid + "A" + SHA1( passwordhash+passwordsalt+DateTime.Now.Date - and embedded that as a parameter in any email links. When clicked, the server can authenticate the member by parsing out memberid (human readable), and then compare the SHA1-part of the ticket by re-generating that part up to 3 days back. In that way, you have links that are valid for 3 days, and pretty hard to guess I think :)